# domain specific ASP.NET MVC5 route with IIS rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I have an MVC5 web application which maps to a domain www.example.com. I'm using basic `{area}/{controller}/{action}` based routing in my webapp and would need to map a subdomain to a specific route.

For example:

`subdomain.example.com` needs to always server content from  `http://example.com/area/controller/action`

Ofcourse the route has to work with ASP.NET MVC5 routing and also all query parameters and "hashbang" data need to be retained so that:

`http://subdomain.example.com#/somethinghere?var=value` redirects content from `http://example.com/area/controller/action#/somethinghere?var=value`

So the question is: is this achievable with IIS routing/rewriting and if so, how? Another option would be to write custom MVC5 route which binds to a domain and I would love to see someone point me to a right direction with that, too.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible, anything after the hash is client side only and the browser will not send it back to the server. As it is not send to the server there is no way to rewrite it.

As an alternative you can consider changing your routing to use pushstate instead of hashstate